# SQL Join commands to discover highest level of product

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So basically what I am trying to do is this... My task is to find people who have "CSM", "LSP" or "CSD" but also joining information from Table "client_personal" that matches the "client_no" from the results of the search on "CSM", "LSP", or "CSD"

Im sure Im doing this all "bass ackwords" but end goal is to show customer information including other fields in table "client_personal" so sales can do a sales pitch for those who have "CSM" but not records of "LSP" or "CSD" (considered higher levels) - Unfortunately there is 1: an assload of mess, tons of dupes, and multiple entries and 2: theres not an easier database to work with that would have "highest level achieved".

```
       SELECT client_no,product,status,paid_date
         FROM client_educational    
    LEFT JOIN client_personal 
           ON client_educational.client_no = client_personal.client_no       
        WHERE product='CSM'
           OR product='LSP'
           OR product='CSD'
```

Heres the databases that I am interested in:

```
    client_educational 

    client_no           product         status          pd_date

    500000              CSM             pd-cert         2018-06-20
    500001              CSM             pd-cert         2018-06-20
    500001              LSP             pd-cert         2018-06-20
    500002              CSM             pd-cert         2018-06-20
    500002              LSP             pd-cert         2018-06-20
    500002              CSD             pd-cert         2018-06-20


    client_personal

    client_no           name            email           phone

    500000              John Doe       mail@mail.com    555-555-5555
    500001              John Shmoe     mail@mail.com    555-555-5555
    500002              John Howe      mail@mail.com    555-555-5555
```

So what Im needing is not only to combine the results, but also display only those who only have product "CSM" but not "LSP" or "CSD" by using the "client_no" row as the unique identifier....

Something like this...

```
    client_no           product         status          pd_date         name            email           phone

    500000              CSM             pd-cert         2018-06-20    John Doe       mail@mail.com    555-555-5555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation checks for your criteria *display only those who only have product "CSM" but not "LSP" or "CSD"*

```
select cp.client_no,cp.name,cp.email,cp.phone
from client_personal cp
join client_educational ce on cp.client_no = ce.client_no
group by cp.client_no,cp.name,cp.email,cp.phone
having sum(ce.product = 'CSM') > 0
and sum(ce.product IN('LSP', 'CSD')) = 0
```

In mysql when an expression is used inside sum(a= b) it will result as a boolean 0/1 so you can get your conditional count using above.

Another way using exists

```
select cp.*
from client_personal cp
join client_educational ce on cp.client_no = ce.client_no 
where ce.product = 'CSM'  
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from client_educational
    where product IN('LSP', 'CSD')
    and client_no = cp.client_no
)
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/TFPSXI98386) for both queries

Comment: That reported data successfully, so I think we are on the right track...

Now, there is many variations of "CSM", for example "CSM1", "CSM2" etc etc.

Would the appropriate modification be something like this??

`having sum(client_educational.product = ('CSM', 'CSM1', 'CSM2''))` @M Khalid Junaid

Comment: @Jon yes its similar but for more than 1 value you need `in()` not `=` like `sum(ce.product IN('CSM', 'CSM1', 'CSM2'))`

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Thank you! This is working perfectly. How can I add more rows to be displayed from client_educational?

Comment: @Jon in second query you can update select list as `select  cp.*, ce.*`, In first query it can't be done in this way

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Figured it out! xD I am learning, sorry for the noobishness

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thank you very much, assigning you as the answer, is there anything else I can do to say thank you??? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jon I suggest you to have a look at [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html), and execute this plan for all queries then you can see which solution is good performance  wise there may be a chance that solution posted by IT WeiHan is good over my solution

Answer (score 1):

Try it use `left join`

```
select 
    T1.`client_no`,
    T2.`product`,
    T2.`status`,
    T2.`pd_date`,
    T1.`name`,
    T1.`email`,
    T1.`phone`
from client_personal T1
left join client_educational T2 on T1.`client_no` = T2.`client_no`
    and T2.`product` = 'CSM'
left join client_educational T3 on T1.`client_no` = T3.`client_no`
    and T3.`product` IN('LSP', 'CSD')
where T2.`client_no` is not null
    and T3.`client_no` is null
```

---

```
| client_no | product | status | pd_date | name | email | phone |
| 500000 | CSM | pd-cert | 2018-06-20 00:00:00 | John Doe | mail@mail.com | 555-555-5555 |
```

---

**TEST DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE client_educational 
    (`client_no` int, `product` varchar(3), `status` varchar(7), `pd_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO client_educational 
    (`client_no`, `product`, `status`, `pd_date`)
VALUES
    (500000, 'CSM', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00'),
    (500001, 'CSM', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00'),
    (500001, 'LSP', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00'),
    (500002, 'CSM', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00'),
    (500002, 'LSP', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00'),
    (500002, 'CSD', 'pd-cert', '2018-06-20 00:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE client_personal
    (`client_no` int, `name` varchar(10), `email` varchar(13), `phone` varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO client_personal
    (`client_no`, `name`, `email`, `phone`)
VALUES
    (500000, 'John Doe', 'mail@mail.com', '555-555-5555'),
    (500001, 'John Shmoe', 'mail@mail.com', '555-555-5555'),
    (500002, 'John Howe', 'mail@mail.com', '555-555-5555')
;
```

---

[DB Fiddle - TEST DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56mbo33bXBTbqowy3FanXu/2)

Comment: I am receiving Error Code 1054. Unknown column 'T2.pd_date' in 'field list'

Comment: Is TEST DDL like your DDL? (like : uppercase/lowercase)

Comment: I guess you can skip `T4` join [Have a look](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56mbo33bXBTbqowy3FanXu/2)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thanks , your answer is clear and great!